# python: avoiding zip truncation of list

Tags: python, list, truncation

I have the following python code that uses zip() and it seems to cause unintended data truncation.

```
inc_data = [[u'Period Ending', u'Dec 31, 2012', u'Dec 31, 2011', u'Dec 31, 2010'],
            [u'Total Revenue\n', u'104,507,100\n', u'106,916,100\n', u'99,870,100\n'],
            [u'Cost of Revenue\n',u'56,000,000\n']
            ]

inc_data2 = zip(*inc_data)
for i in inc_data2:
    print i
```

It only prints:

```
(u'Period Ending', u'Total Revenue\n', u'Cost of Revenue\n')
(u'Dec 31, 2012', u'104,507,100\n', u'56,000,000\n')
```

But I want it to print the following, but apparently I have to add in fillers `u''` by hand in order to prevent zip() from truncating the inc_data.  But I don't know how to code that.

```
(u'Period Ending', u'Total Revenue\n', u'Cost of Revenue\n')
(u'Dec 31, 2012', u'104,507,100\n', u'56,000,000\n')
(u'Dec 31, 2011', u'106,916,100\n', u'')
(u'Dec 31, 2010', u'99,870,100\n', u'')
```

To describe inc_data above,

```
inc_data = [ [x],
             [y],
             [z] ]
```

How do I make x, y and z to be the same length? And the length is the max length of x, y, or z?

```
(u'Period Ending', u'Total Revenue\n', u'Cost of Revenue\n')
(u'Dec 31, 2012', u'104,507,100\n', u'56,000,000\n')
(u'Dec 31, 2011', u'106,916,100\n', u'')
(u'Dec 31, 2010', u'99,870,100\n', u'')
```

Sorry for the lengthy and wordy explanation of the problem.  Could you help me or point me to a similar question that has been answered, if one exists?  many thanks!

Comment: Use [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) with `fillvalue=u''`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

inc_data = [[u'Period Ending', u'Dec 31, 2012', u'Dec 31, 2011', u'Dec 31, 2010'],
            [u'Total Revenue\n', u'104,507,100\n', u'106,916,100\n', u'99,870,100\n'],
            [u'Cost of Revenue\n',u'56,000,000\n']
            ]

print list(izip_longest(*inc_data, fillvalue=u'')) 


# [(u'Period Ending', u'Total Revenue\n', u'Cost of Revenue\n'), 
   (u'Dec 31, 2012', u'104,507,100\n', u'56,000,000\n'), 
   (u'Dec 31, 2011', u'106,916,100\n', u''), 
   (u'Dec 31, 2010', u'99,870,100\n', u'')]
```

Comment: izip_longest works perfectly.  Once the data is transposed with izip_longest, do you know how I can delete the first line so that I don't have (u'Period Ending', u'Total Revenue\n', u'Cost of Revenue\n')?  Essentially, I will be storing the data in a sqlite3 table.  many thanks!

Comment: Use a [slice:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]][1:]=[[3, 4], [5, 6]]` The slice of `list[1:]` would remove the first list of tuples. So you could do: `list(izip_longest(*inc_data, fillvalue=u''))[1:]` for example

Comment: Thanks.  Trial and error yield the results you gave me.  I didn't know it is called slice, so I wasn't able to search for that technique.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In Python 3, the function is called `zip_longest`.

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2.x:**

Use [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

inc_data = [[u'Period Ending', u'Dec 31, 2012', u'Dec 31, 2011', u'Dec 31, 2010'],
            [u'Total Revenue\n', u'104,507,100\n', u'106,916,100\n', u'99,870,100\n'],
            [u'Cost of Revenue\n',u'56,000,000\n']
            ]
  
print list(izip_longest(*inc_data, fillvalue=u'')) 


# [(u'Period Ending', u'Total Revenue\n', u'Cost of Revenue\n'), 
   (u'Dec 31, 2012', u'104,507,100\n', u'56,000,000\n'), 
   (u'Dec 31, 2011', u'106,916,100\n', u''), 
   (u'Dec 31, 2010', u'99,870,100\n', u'')]
```

**Python 3.xx:**

[izip_longest()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) has been renamed to [zip_longest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)
Use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

inc_data = [[u'Period Ending', u'Dec 31, 2012', u'Dec 31, 2011', u'Dec 31, 2010'],
            [u'Total Revenue\n', u'104,507,100\n', u'106,916,100\n', u'99,870,100\n'],
            [u'Cost of Revenue\n',u'56,000,000\n']
            ]
  
print list(zip_longest(*inc_data, fillvalue=u'')) 


# [(u'Period Ending', u'Total Revenue\n', u'Cost of Revenue\n'), 
   (u'Dec 31, 2012', u'104,507,100\n', u'56,000,000\n'), 
   (u'Dec 31, 2011', u'106,916,100\n', u''), 
   (u'Dec 31, 2010', u'99,870,100\n', u'')]
```